# A block does not get executed when passing self

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

I have a strange error when i am using a block.

option a works and option b does not.
when it does not work it does not even execute NSLog,meaning it does not even enter the block.

block being passed to ConnectionManager:

```
[[ConnectionManager sharedConnectionManager]connect:OnSuccess:^{
   NSLog(@"check that it enters the block");
   MylayerClass* myLayer = [[MyLayerClass alloc]init];
   //a
   [[BaseLayer instance] addChild:myLayer];
   //b
   [self addChild:myLayer];
   [myLayer release];
}];
```

within ConnectionManager that block gets set as a private property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onConnectionSuccess)();
//...
@syntesize onConnectionSuccess;
//... 
onConnectionSuccess = successBlock
```

and later gets called when a connection was established.

what could be causing this?

Comment: Are there any UI-related operations involved (you must do all UI-manipulation on the main thread...)?

Comment: this might be a dumb thing, but is the block even set? or are you calling a method on a nil object?

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling block in option b?

Comment: Is there any error block?

Comment: You are passing 'MyLayer' and not 'myLayer'.

Comment: Please post the definition of connect:OnSuccess method.